# Classification errors on 'bert-base-uncased' text classifier

Tags: nlp, multiclass-classification, bert, text-classification

Disclaimer : This is a long question, please be patient. Thanks in advance

I am using *bert-base-uncased* for text-classification. I have 11 classes, and the classification is happening alright for most of the classes. But of these 11 classes there are three classes, say **A, B and C**. Where there are high misclassification errors. I wish to reduce the errors between these classes.

Current State of my model :

1. Model used Hugging Face *bert-base-uncased*.
2. Loss function : Weighted Cross Entropy where the weights represent the inverse of the fraction of each class in the data.
3. The text data related to classes A, B and C are not unbalanced and are roughly comparable to the most populous class

My Questions :

1. Can anyone say why is this occuring?
2. I am thinking of using some-other loss function specifically for these three classes, say soft-F1 from torchmetrics. The idea is that nn.Cross_Entropy() will be used for all classes and apart from that I will use soft-F1 when the true_label belongs to these three classes.

Thus the final loss function will be `loss = frac * $nn.Cross_entropy() + (1-frac) * torchmetrics.soft_f1(if true_label in [A, B, C])`, where `frac` is an hyper-parameter.

Will this approach work, or should I use something else ?

Comment: It could be because for the classes A, B C there are very few samples available to train the model on.

Comment: No that is not the case, I mentioned that in the question. Each class has 3000+ examples and the whole data by itself is under 25000 examples. Thus they are well represented

Comment: You can try making all the other classes as 0 and class A as 1 for one model, then do the same for other two classes. Basically making 3 models for each class and finally concatenate the results so you can get the final result.

Comment: That is a very crude method, can you suggest some loss function based approach so that I can minimize that and increase F1 score

Comment: try fbeta_score. You can tune it's values based on what you need. Example he parameter beta controls the trade-off between precision and recall:                    - If beta is 1, it is the F1 score, which equally weights precision and recall.
- If beta is greater than 1, more emphasis is put on recall (capturing more true positives).
- If beta is less than 1, more emphasis is put on precision (reducing false positives).

Comment: Will do thanks. Can I combine it with Cross_entropy() and use a hybrid function ?

Comment: @VinayVarahabhotla, I understand that the misclassification errors happen in a held-out test set, right? How was the train-test split done? Does the problem still happen with a different train-test split?

Comment: Yes , I took care that no data leakage happens and the errors persisted during multiple training runs

Comment: I understand that you mean that on each training run the train/test split was different, right?

Comment: Yes that's right